Solo traveling Japan or with a tour group?
Has anyone traveled Japan both with a tour group and by themselves/with their own party that only speaks English? Trying to see which one is personally more preferred.
I figure the tour group can visit more places efficiently and arrange hotels/transportation, which might be a hassle to do ourselves if we only speak English.
On the other hand, traveling without a tour group allows you more time flexibility in places you want to stay longer in, sleeping in, etc. I think some tour groups allow you the experience of staying in a traditional ryokan inn with onsen hot springs, as well as yokocho restaurant alley nightlife, but no overnight sleeper train experience. (So if tour group travel is better, should I just ride the overnight sleeper train myself and do the rest of the trip with a tour group?)
Also considering price differences, I've heard tour groups can be cheaper if they're getting bulk pricing from hotels/buses/trains, but solo travel can also be cheaper in some scenarios, especially if using hostels and capsule hotels. But is it worth dealing with potential language barriers to save that money?

I have done a combination, week with a tourgroup followed by two weeks train pass and youth hostels, on my own without problems. But that was 1994, so maybe not longer relevant.

I've been in Japan on a couple of occasions and didn't have any issues with English-only communications. As long as you stay on the beaten path you should be fine. Keep some cash in your pockets though.

Solo travel in Japan is not a problem these days. The country catered to 23 million tourists in 2023 and already smashed that record by September 2024 with a quarter of the year left to go.

Hotels can easily be booked online using both the usual Western suspects (Booking etc) or the English versions of local sites (Jalan, Rakuten, etc).
Long distance trains can be bought online, from vending machines, or from station staff in English.
Local transport across the entire country can be paid for by tapping your Suica/Pasmo card, so there's no need to work out complex fares.
You can navigate easily with Google Maps.
The touristy bits of Tokyo, Kyoto and Osaka are used to foreign tourists and English menus are common.
In a pinch, you can always use Google Translate to read signs and communicate.

For most travellers, organized tours will be more expensive, because you're paying for the guide and the agency's cut. Plus you'll be shunted to the hotels, restaurants and gift shops that pay the highest commission. Joining one is easier though, because you don't need to plan ahead, everything is taken care of.
Also, since you mentioned sleeper trains, there are only two regular sleeper services left in Japan and they go to places that aren't particularly popular with tourists (Takamatsu and Izumo). There are some very expensive luxury touring trains, but you don't need a travel agency for those, just book directly.

We've done Japan on our own also with local guides (friends of a friend). Both were very good experience. Japan is very safe and easy to maneuver. You can get by with English just fine. While many older people don't speak it, youngers typically do and there is often someone around who can facilitate communication.
Public transportation is excellent, but takes a little learning to properly decode. Google Maps is indeed very helpful. If you are planning to cover a sizable part of the country, I would recommend looking into a JR Rail Pass. It's a very convenient way to get around and the train system is very reliable. Unfortunately the recently increased the prices substantially in Sep 2023 (we go lucky at our last trip June 2023). Japan is  not a budget destination.
We never bothered getting a Suica/Pasmo card since our JR pass covered a lot of our local travel as well and I found it difficult to figure out which card is accepted where for what purposes.
The downsides of a professional tour group are IMO size and itinerary. Some of the most fun experience we had were random explorations: we ended up in small guesthouses sleeping on Tatamis and using their local Onsen (hot bath) or in tiny eateries with just 2 or 3 tables and you more or less eat what they got.  I don't think this can happen on an organized tour but that certainly depends on your personal preferences.
Most Japanese are quite tolerant and friendly to strangers. Some are less so, but worst that will happen they will ignore you or go into "very formal" mode. They will always be polite no matter what. Again, there is an advantage to traveling solo: singles or a couple in non-touristy places will be treated friendlier than a larger group in a touristy place.

IC cards are accepted almost anywhere a tourist will go. I have been refused service before for not speaking the language so I won't say they will always be polite.

I have travelled Solo in Japan and had absolutely no Problem. From planning to Ticket/Hotel bookings , everything went smooth.
Group tours offer advantage of taking away overhead of planning , it also provides you some company but then you cannot plan your way and always have to go with group. So its a personal preference.
From financial management perspective also group tours are better, as you know total cost upfront. I will not say group tours are cheaper, it depends upon which one you choose.
Food can be an issue if you are a vegetarian, this is another aspect where group tours are better. Tour will have food options sorted out in advance.
You can always plan small group tours during your trip to certain destinations. It works out well especially for remote places.
If you like freedom, dynamic planning and are happy to take overhead of planning then Solo travels can be amazing.
